# I want dropwizard to return HTTP 500 responses as JSON

Tags: dropwizard

I am new to dropwizard.  I am using version 0.8.5 of dropwizard.  I have a dropwizard REST service that returns JSON when the call is successful and HTTL when the call is not successful, like with HTTP status codes of 500 or 404.

happy path

```
LOGGER.info("Cached userinfo for '{}'",username);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("ticketId",created.getTicketId());
json.put("token", token);
return Response.ok(json.toString()).build();
```

unhappy path

```
if (created.getTicketId() == null) {
LOGGER.error("Email not sent, ticket not created");
return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

Here is the curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"WPf3s0G1M"}' http://localhost:7777/ids-rest-api/password/reset
```

And here is the reply from that curl, I want this reply in JSON:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Request failed.</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /ids-rest-api/password/reset. Reason:
<pre>    Request failed.</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small>    </i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you confirm the version you're using, please. The [dropwizard site](http://www.dropwizard.io/about/release-notes.html) seems to indicate they're only up to 0.8.2 so far.

Answer (score 5):

Your method will work if you add an entity to the response, even if its an empty JSON object such as this

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/error")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BrokenResource {

    @GET
    public Response getServerError() {
        return Response.serverError().entity("{}").build();
    }
}
```

Explicitly stating the type can be removed if the method or class is annotated with @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) to save you some time.

Answer (score 2):

I think that throwing `WebApplicationException` works fine.

should:

```
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;

...

throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

instead of:

```
Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
   .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

where you need to annotate your method or resource class with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

Then the response will be JSON format like:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error"
}
```